# wkhtmltopdf with silverstripe 3.2

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, silverstripe

I'm playing around with pdf generation. After the silverstripe modules for dompdf and tcppdf which doesn't work like I want them to, I came across BetterBrief's module for wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/BetterBrief/silverstripe-pdf

It should be exactly what I need but I can't figure out why it's not creating pdfs. I installed it with composer following the module instructions, after that I installed the debian application and set up a demo template with just three words in it to test ist. But the pdf file can't be created.

The error I receive is the following and not very helpful to me http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5676bac4a4186

perhapse someone had the same problem or knows a solution for that.

the creation of a pdf from commandline works

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

**Edit** That's not a real solution for this problem, but an alternativ to create a pdf with SilverStripe and wkhtmltopdf. https://github.com/creativeSynergy/silverstripe-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: how come tcpdf didn't work? I've found that the most reliable and requires no additional server installations...

Comment: Tcpdf is working but it's not working as I want it to ;) I need CSS3 support and for that wkhtmltopdf is perfect

Answer (score 3):

A quick google shows it has something to do with wkhtmltopdf needing X to work.
https://github.com/knplabs/snappy/issues/20

Comment: i'm sry, i simply forget to install it on my server ... i just used the module and its php dependencies ...

Comment: Do you get that error message when calling the url in a browser? if you SS is in dev mode and you have display errors on it will halt on all errors. Try running silverstripe in live mode or limit the php error levels. That error message is a warning and can be something that you can ignore. But of course I'd suggest on fixing all level issues.

Comment: I know, SS is in dev mode and all PHP errors are displayed. The error appears if I call the function in Browser.

Comment: @csy_dot_io DID you try to do actually what I suggested? E.g Run ss in live mode OR suppress the WARNING level errors. Does it generate the PDF then? The error says its trying to unlink a file that is not in the filesystem > thus the WARNING, but not a FATAL ERROR so you could ignore that one.

Comment: @FinBoWa sry, I didn't get around to test that. But even if this would work, I like my SilverStripe error and warning free ;) I came around this error by writing my own module, a simple wrapper based on an other wkhtmltopdf wrapper https://github.com/creativeSynergy/silverstripe-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @csy_dot_io me too but remember that you aren't responsible of the 3rd party module :). If it works you can use it. Warning level messages don't necessary mean a broken software.